# my web page encoding is gbk，But grunt-contrib-connect output encoding is utf-8:

Tags: grunt-contrib-connect

my web page encoding is `gbk`，But `grunt-contrib-connect` output encoding is `utf-8`:

```
Connection:keep-alive
content-length:3457
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

so, my page becomes garbled. I know there may be is connect npm's problem，but I do not know how to solve.

I hope to get help here, thank you！

Comment: It's so rare that `gbk` is used; you'd better change to `utf-8` instead.

Comment: So the 1.2 billion people in China who can read simplified Chinese represents an "edge case"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert character encoding from CP932 to UTF-8 in nodejs javascript, using the nodejs-iconv module (or other solution)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411570/how-to-convert-character-encoding-from-cp932-to-utf-8-in-nodejs-javascript-usin)